# Scaling of Spring boot microservice with Redis cache

Tags: spring-boot, design-patterns, redis, architecture

I have a Spring boot application that gets messages from ActiveMQ Artemis and then stores them in Redis cache. Of course processes the messages as well and stores any results in the same Redis Cache.

If I am to scale it horizontally, I would have two or three instances of the Spring Boot microservice running. Each instance will get a message that the other two will not. that instance will process that message and save both in the redis cache. One way is to have one redis cache as the backend. but then we may have three MS accessing the same redis cache. So lets say each Spring boot MS has its own Redis cache. Then how do I solve the issue where each redis cache has different data. But I the processing of a message from ActiveMQ i would need a combined data and combined result.

What are different strategies to solve this issue?